# My code outputs invalid when I input anything

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a random number generator with C++. I want the random number generator to be able to generate both decimal numbers or whole numbers, depending on what the user picks. I have coded up to where the system picks a random whole number (if the user selected whole number). My problem is when the user inputs anything, including one of the choices, it still outputs invalid.

I have sifted through the code several times, attempting to find the problem. I am fairly new to coding, so I may have missed something.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>

int main() {
  int whole_number;
  double decimal_number;
  std::string user_input = "invalid";
  std::string yes_or_no = "invalid";
  whole_number = 0;
  decimal_number = 0;
  double dec1 = 0;
  int wh1 = 0;
  std::cout << "\n1-100 RANDOM NUMBER GENERATOR\n";
  label1:
  std::cout << "\n\nType what kind of random number you want to generate:\n\n";
  std::cout << "Type whole number to generate a whole number\n";
  std::cout << "Type decimal number to generate a decimal number\n";
  label3:
  std::cin >> user_input;
  if (user_input == "whole number") {
      std::cout << "You have selected: whole number\nWould you like to pick again?\nyes/no\n";
      goto label2;
  }
  else if (user_input == "decimal number") {
      std::cout << "You have selected: decimal number\nWould you like to pick again?\nyes/no\n";
      goto label2;
  }
  else {
      std::cout << "\nInvalid, try again.\n\n";
      goto label3;
  }
  label2:
  std::cin >> yes_or_no;
  if (yes_or_no == "yes") {
      goto label1;
  }
  else if (yes_or_no == "no") {
      goto label4;
  }
  label4:
  if (user_input == "whole number") {
      wh1 = rand() % 100 + 1;
  }
}
```

I expected the code to move on to where it asks if you want to re enter your choice, but instead it outputs the following:

Invalid, try again.

Invalid, try again.

Comment: "I am trying to create a random number ..." - Your first stop should be : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random

Comment: FYI, after you get it working, your very next assignment is to re-write it without using `goto`. If you can't write C++ code without using `goto` statements, you will have a hard time finding anybody else who wants to read your code.

Comment: @SolomonSlow: Yes, and some of these `goto` statements aren't even really doing anything. The `goto label2;` and `goto label4;` statements could be deleted without any effect.

Comment: Search the internet for "c++ transform string toupper tolower".  You'll want to convert the reply to either all upper case or all lower case, so you'll only need to make one comparison.

Comment: The code in your `if` statement would be easier to read if you use one `cout` per line (like you did near the top of the function).

Answer (score 2):

The `>>` operator for `std::string` reads only up to the first whitespace character. So you'd only ever see "whole" or "decimal", which doesn't match what you're checking for.

I'd recommend using [`getline()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) instead. It will read an entire line of input.